# React Hook function Component prevent re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I have a Class React component, that uses a functional Hook component if the browser pathName is /exp

When the page loads up, my app component changes is state about 3-4 times,

How can I prevent the Example hook from remounting if the prop has not changed ?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

 function Example() {
  console.log("i mounted")
  }
```

__

```
export default class App extends Component {
state={key:"value"}   <--------------------------------------MAIN APP STATE CHANGES 3 times
componentDidMount(){
//I change App state 3 times with conditional code 
}

 render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
        <Route path="/exp">
            <Example prop="I have not changed"  />  <-----------------PREVENT MULTIPLE MOUNTINGS
        </Route>
            </Switch>
         </Router>
         )
}
```

Comment: Consider to use `export default React.memo(App)`

Comment: Well App is not a functional component, I dont think I can use React.memo there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const Chat = React.memo(props => {
  console.log("Greeting Comp render");
  return <></>
});

export default Chat   
//This worked for me
```

You can use [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) and render when prop change

```
function MyComponent(props) {
  /* render using props */
}

function areEqual(prevProps, nextProps) {
  /*
  return true if passing nextProps to render would return
  the same result as passing prevProps to render,
  otherwise return false
  */
}
export default React.memo(MyComponent, areEqual);
```

or

[shouldcomponentupdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) if class component

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)
```

*Note: This method only exists as a performance optimization. Do not rely on it to “prevent” a render, as this can lead to bugs.*

Comment: I'll have to read the docs, I did a copy paste and MyComponent is still rendering multiple times

Comment: you can try using PureComponent https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent

Comment: const Chat = React.memo(props => {
  console.log("Greeting Comp render");
  return <></>
});

export default Chat

This worked